# How to bringing an offline filegroup to online?

Tags: sql-server, filegroup

I took one of my database filegroups offline . I want to know is there any way to bring this offline filegroup online?

Prior thanks to your answers.

Comment: How did you take it offline?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring it back online with restoring from backup.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-2017

> A file set to OFFLINE can only be set online by restoring the file
>   from backup

Answer (score -2):

To make a database online/offline you can use the following commands in you master database context.

**Database Offline**

```
ALTER DATABASE Database_Name SET OFFLINE;
```

**Database Online**

```
ALTER DATABASE Database_Name SET ONLINE;
```

**Edit**
Restore you File with "With Recovery" Option. something like this ..

```
RESTORE DATABASE DatabaeName 
FILEGROUP='C' 
WITH RECOVERY
```

Comment: This is not about database , my question is about filegroups.